# .htaccess not taking effect even with AllowOverride All

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Windows.

Nothing in the `.htaccess` file is working, although the necessary stuff in `c:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` are set:

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I've put the same `.htaccess` file in both `c:\Apache24\htdocs\myproject` and `c:\Apache24\htdocs` just to make sure.

This is the content of `.htaccess`:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myproject/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.**

My Apache started to deteriorate, at a point it didn't even execute .php files*.
In my final despair **I opened the Windows task manager > Services, and restarted Apache.** Not only did Apache parse the .php files then, but **the .htaccess problem went away** too. Normal command line Apache restart never worked. This is some mysterious stuff.

This should be a great help for many.

* (There was a short while, when I used the original `httpd.conf` file, which didn't contain the php settings, then I moved back to the proper `httpd.conf` file very soon. From what it seems, this is what took effect 5 days later. I know this sounds pretty stupid, but that's the best explanation.)